# Table of contents with articles adressed

Tags: table-of-contents, article, journal

I'm quite newbie to LaTeX, so I need some help. I'm trying to create a *very simple* journal using this template: http://www.howtotex.com/images/newsletter-howtotex-screen.png

The question: what's the most effective way to adress several articles with a Table of contents? I was trying to add a TOC in this template, but the results are quite frustrating ---I can't add the sections properly and the template is mess up when I try to adjust the TOC :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please provide us with a minimal working example. The link leads to a picture file. Without code, everything will be guess work and the resulting misunderstandings will be frustrating for all of us.

Comment: The document template contains a `\NewsItem` command -- it's quite easy to use a `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}` in that command, adding the title of the article to the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the template and added a `\addcontentsline` to the `\NewsItem` code...it will provide a section style entry to the TOC.

I did not check the typographic style of this template and other possible weirdness in there.

The look of the ToC should possible adapted to the style of the newsletter

```
%%% LaTeX Template: Newsletter
%%%
%%% Source: http://www.howtotex.com/
%%% Feel free to distribute this template, but please keep the referal to HowToTeX.com.
%%% Date: September 2011


%%% ---------------
%%% PREAMBLE
%%% ---------------
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Define geometry (without using the geometry package)
\setlength\topmargin{-48pt}
\setlength\headheight{0pt}
\setlength\headsep{25pt}
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt}
\setlength\textwidth{7.0in}
\setlength\textheight{9.5in}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-30pt}
\setlength\evensidemargin{-30pt}

\frenchspacing                      % better looking spacing

% Call packages we'll need
\usepackage[english]{babel}         % english
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}             % images
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}        % math
\usepackage{multicol}               % three-column layout
\usepackage{url}                    % clickable links
\usepackage{marvosym}               % symbols
\usepackage{wrapfig}                % wrapping text around figures
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % font encoding
\usepackage{charter}                % Charter font for main content
\usepackage{blindtext}              % dummy text
\usepackage{datetime}               % custom date
    \newdateformat{mydate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\usepackage[%pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
            colorlinks=false]{hyperref} % links and pdf behaviour

% Customize (header and) footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{ \footnotesize 
        Newletter from HowToTeX.com \\
        \Mundus\ \href{http://www.howtotex.com}{HowToTeX.com}   \quad
        \Telefon\ 555-5555                                          \quad
        \Letter\ \href{mailto:frits@howtotex.com}{frits@howtotex.com}
      }
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\footnotesize ~\\ Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}    % no bar on top of page
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}    % bar on bottom of page

%%% ---------------
%%% DEFINITIONS
%%% ---------------

% Define separators
\newcommand{\HorRule}[1]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} % Creating a horizontal rule
\newcommand{\SepRule}{\noindent                          % Creating a separator
                        \begin{center}
                            \rule{250pt}{1pt}
                        \end{center}
                        }                       

% Define Title en News input
\newcommand{\JournalName}[1]{%
        \begin{center}  
            \Huge \usefont{T1}{augie}{m}{n}
            #1%
        \end{center}    
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\JournalIssue}[1]{%
        \hfill \textsc{\mydate \today, No #1}
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewsItem}[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
        \usefont{T1}{augie}{m}{n}   
        \large #1 \vspace{4pt}
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewsAuthor}[1]{%
            \hfill by \textsc{#1} \vspace{4pt}
            \par \normalfont}       


%%% ---------------
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
%%% ---------------
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
% Title 
% -----
\JournalIssue{1}
\JournalName{Science \& Technology}
\noindent\HorRule{3pt} \\[-0.75\baselineskip]
\HorRule{1pt}
% -----

% Front article
% -----
\vspace{0.5cm}
    \SepRule
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.75\linewidth}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.41\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
        \\  % this spacer is needed to make the text on the right fit OK
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \NewsItem{Frog eats monkey}
    \emph{\blindtext}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
% -----


% Other news (1)
% -----
\vspace{0.5cm}
    \SepRule
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \NewsItem{Monkey eats elephant}
    \NewsAuthor{F. Wenneker}
    \blindtext[2] 
% -----

\vspace{1cm}
% Other news (2)
% -----
\NewsItem{Elephant eats frog}
\NewsAuthor{J. Doe}
    \blindtext[1]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{elephant}
        \end{center}
        \blindtext[1]
\end{multicols}
% -----
\end{document}
```

[image]